# I am trying to make an invoice splitting table and I'm having trouble with an excessively long formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to split items on an invoice between different entities quickly with the totals for each entity at the bottom. 
I want to know if there is a better way than the "x" and:

```
 =IF(M2="x",$BA$2,0)+IF(M3="x",$BA$3,0)+IF(M4="x",$BA$4,0)+IF(M5="x",$BA$5,0)+IF(M6="x",$BA$6,0)+IF(M7="x",$BA$7,0)+IF(M8="x",$BA$8,0)+IF(M9="x",$BA$9,0)+IF(M10="x",$BA$10,0)+IF(M11="x",$BA$11,0)+IF(M12="x",$BA$12,0)+IF(M13="x",$BA$13,0)+IF(M14="x",$BA$14,0)+IF(M15="x",$BA$15,0)+IF(M16="x",$BA$16,0)+IF(M17="x",$BA$17,0)+IF(M18="x",$BA$18,0)+IF(M19="x",$BA$19,0)
```

Any assistance on streamlining this would be fantastic. Side notes: billable rates are different per item and all items are being split evenly.

[Excel table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChTnd.jpg)

Comment: I'm thinking you may be looking for `COUNTIF` or `SUMIF` but I,m not sure. Can you clarify what you are trying to accomplish? I've looked at the screencap and I can't figure out where the numbers you get on the bottom row come from.

Comment: The general idea on what I'm trying to do is split each row automatically with 'x'. The first row is 630 dollars for 1.5 hours of work for example. If the work was done on entities 104, 307, 701, and 707 the bill should be split four ways. At the bottom, I want the sum of all portions relating to each entity. So entity 104 took part in items 1 and 2, so the sum is their portion of each item. The forumla listed above is in each cell (obvious changed slightly) at the bottom as my way of summing their portions. It is too long though and I feel like what I'm trying to do could be done much easier.

Comment: also, the last two rows are a count formula and the total billed amount divided by the number of x's. I have to do this for dozens of invoices and I don't want to have to do it manually for each one. If the table isn't needed and I can do it in an easier way that transfers invoices well, I'd happily do that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use a `SUMIF`:

This would be the total for column `D`

```
=SUMIF(D2:D18,"x",$Z2:$Z18)
```

(I was too lazy to count all those columns, so assumes column `Z` was the rightmost one with the divided totals, adjust as needed)

Comment: That is fantastic, thank you! I tried something similar, but I wasn't having any success.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing a bit more of your model it is hard to say the best solution. My first thought is to add a helper column to do the math with a easy formula and then hide it. In the screen cap I used column A, but it could be any column.

[image]

Comment: I unfortunately can't show more of the model as it is sensitive information. Is there anything I can add to clarify?

Comment: I want it to be summing all X's in a particular column (say 101) and take their portion of each row with an x. For 101, it would add 567, 420, 1222, and 75 because that is 101's portion of those four items on the invoice. Does that make sense?

Comment: Assuming all the 101 items are in the same column you could use sumifs to get his. So an example if all 101 items are in column BA and the Xs are in M Then =SUMIFS(BA:BA,M:M,"X"). In this case it will only add items from column AB if they have an X in column M.